# Game doesn't run a correct fps

Tags: java, runtime, 2d, frame-rate

so I am making a simple 2d game in Java. I am only using 1 thread and set the game to run off 120 fps, since this game isn't resource heavy almost any computer should be able to run this, infact my friends computer thats like 8 years old can run it at 120fps, but I can't, well not always, I know my computer is fast enough, it a home built computer with really good specs. At first it was able to run it easily at 120 fps, but lately when I try to run the game it stops at 63-64 fps, I have made no changes to my games code since it was running at 120 fps. I am not using any libraries I'm just using Graphics g2d and sprites.

I don't know really what code I should include, this is my main thread:

```
time = new Timer(8, this);
        time.start();
```

I also included my jar file which can be ran(for testing of fps) or decompiled. 
(http://www.4shared.com/file/pdXXyxr8/Game.html)
I know this is a kinda bad post but I really don't know what to include it a really odd problem that seems to be more related to runtime and random probability then code.

Comment: Hello, there's no need to publish jar files or something compiled. I think no one would download an unkown binary file and run it on a computer. Profile your code. Run profiler to find bottlenecks in your performance. And when there's a bit of code that you cannot profile, show it there.

Answer (score 0):

A Swing Timer is never absolutely reliable about its time slices, and this is doubly true at very small slices as you're using. I would use the time delay constant as a rough suggestion of what size the time slice *might* be, but would get the system time and measure the actual time slice and base my model's changes, such as distance a sprite moves, on the actual time slice size.

Comment: This is true also.. I used System.nanoTime() to measure intervals and base sprite movement on the actual elapsed frame-interval, since millis time is horribly jumpy & inaccurate (18.2 ms ticks, on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're in debug mode, breakpoints (especially conditional ones) are enabled, or something?

Otherwise, go back in version-control til the speed recovers. If you don't have version control, backup the entire project and then cut code out -- aim for 50% each time -- until the speed recovers. This is essentially a "binary search" strategy by removing code, to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using System.nanoTime(); also I would not set the game to be at 120fps, rather I would have it depend on the frequency of the monitor.  For a simple game you shouldn't require 120fps unless you are making a stereoscopic dependent game.